# angularjs focus on element on mobile devices

Tags: angularjs, mobile, cross-browser

I am developing a single page application using angularjs and hope that it works across browsers. However, when I tested it on my nexus 5 phone, problem occurs when I try to navigate through different functionality on a **zoomed in screen** the center is always at **the center of the whole page** which sometimes give users the illusion that they are on a blank page (since active elements are on the top left corner of the page) Is there an easy way to put focus on specific elements of page when redirect happens? Thanks.

Comment: How are you redirecting the page? using angular-ui-router or ngRoute?

Comment: I am just using $location.url() to change the page @V31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the $routeChangeSuccess event of $route and in that you can make use of $anchorscroll service.

Code Snippet:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (scope, next, current) {
    $location.hash('<ur top div id>');
    $anchorScroll();
}
```

You need to inject dependency for anchorScroll for the same.

[ngRoute Documentation for routeChangeSuccess event](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)